# Why are rollbacks needed?

Tags: database, rollback

Why are rollbacks so important?

Is it to prevent data (like data in a SQL DB) from being in an inconsistent state?

If so, how comes the data "store" (the SQL DB or whatever) made it possible in the first place to become in a corrupt state?

Are there data storage mechanisms that don't have a need for "rollbacks"?

Comment: Note that this is definitely not homework...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases, when you need insert/update data in many related tables - if you didn't have transactional logic, then any errors somewhere in middle of process could make data inconsistent.

Simple example. Say you need to insert both order header data into orders table and order lines into lines table. You insert order header, read identity, start inserting order lines - but this second insert fails on whatever reason. Only reliable way to recover from this situation is to rollback first insert - either explicitly (when your connection to db is alive) or implicitly (when link is gone down).

Answer (score 4):

Rollbacks are important in case of any kind of errors appearing during database operational. They can really save the day in case of database server crashes or a critical exception is thrown in an application that modifies contents of DB. When a significant DB operation is performed (i.e. updates, inserts, etc.) and the process is broken in the middle, it would be very hard to trace which operations were successful and usage of DB afterward would be very complicated.

The "store" itself does not generally have a built-in mechanism for consistency control - this is exactly why we use rollbacks and transactions. This can be perceived as a sort of 'live backup' mechanism.

Comment: +1, thanks... But how comes that when significant DB operations are performed the DB itself isn't more reliable?  Isn't it kinda weird that a significant operation can fail and then leave the DB in an inconsistent state? (I mean, I know that's how SQL DBs work, but isn't that a very poor feature of SQLs DBs?)

Comment: @Gugussee: that's not always DB fault - of course, sometimes it just happens that rats will eat network cables and disconnect the DB in the middle of world-saving data processing, but it quite often happens that DB is manipulated by external applications that perform consecutive DB operations. These applications can be faulty, resulting in some runtime errors and thus not being able to complete the logical set of operations. DB just cannot be 'wise' enough to know what the application is all about and return itself to state before the modifications.

Comment: Like I said in my response - most consistency problems are related with multiple table operations, where consistency is required at business layer. DB itself doesn't (and can't) care about related data logical consistency - it can track only relations technical integrity.